# JBoss EAP 7.2 installer for RHEL 7

Tags: jboss

We are currently trying to setup the JBoss EAP 7.2 on RHEL 7, but have some question on which installer that we should use.

The scenario is, we are currently setting up the production environment to be used as a user testing environment, upon which passed successfully, will be promoted as a production environment. Client prefers to purchase the JBoss and thus activate the JBoss subscription license only when the test is passed.

As such, we would only be able to install using the Developer edition. My question is, if we use that to install in the server, once we get the actual subscription license, do we need to reinstall the app server?

What is the difference between the developer edition and the full subscription edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in the installer provided in developer edition. You can use it, get your hands dirty and promote it to Production with a subscription. There are no hidden features or any difference in the binaries. You don't need to reinstall it after getting a subscription. You can use the zip installer to make it portable as well.